# Java ignoring setBounds

Tags: java

I am a student learning java ahead of my comp sci class, and my teacher knows nothing about JFrames or JButtons, so I'm reaching out here. This is my overarching program to learn about JFrames, the first menu it opens up just fine, sometimes it will set the bounds of buttons correctly, but sometimes it ignores it and fills the frame, sometimes one button, sometimes its different buttons, I couldn't find any other threads on here with the same situation, so I figured I would ask.

````
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.Random;
public class programToEndAllPrograms {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Choose a Program");
        JButton TempConverter = new JButton();
        TempConverter.setText("Temperature Converter");
        TempConverter.setBounds(50,155,200,50);
        TempConverter.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(TempConverter);
        JButton CurrentTime = new JButton();
        CurrentTime.setText("Current Time");
        CurrentTime.setBounds(50,105,200,50);
        CurrentTime.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(CurrentTime);
        JButton RussianRoulette = new JButton();
        RussianRoulette.setText("Russian Roulette");
        RussianRoulette.setBounds(50,55,200,50);
        RussianRoulette.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(RussianRoulette);
        JButton DaysSinceLastTrinket = new JButton();
        DaysSinceLastTrinket.setText("Days Since Last Trinket");
        DaysSinceLastTrinket.setBounds(50,15,200,50);
        DaysSinceLastTrinket.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(DaysSinceLastTrinket);
        frame.add(title);
        JButton SimpleCalculator = new JButton();
        SimpleCalculator.setText("Simple Calculator");
        SimpleCalculator.setBounds(50,205,200,50);
        SimpleCalculator.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(SimpleCalculator);
        
        TempConverter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tempConverter();
            }
        });
        SimpleCalculator.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                simpleCalculator();
            }
        });
        CurrentTime.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                currentTime();
            }
        });
        RussianRoulette.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                russianRoulette();
            }
        });
        DaysSinceLastTrinket.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                daysSinceLastTrinket();
            }
        });
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Choose a program from the list:");
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }```
````

Comment: Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion, too many factors go into determine how best a component should be sized and positioned.  Take the time to learn and understand how to make use of the available layout managers - see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).  Remember, you're not stuck to a single container/layout, you can compound these together to produce very complex UIs

Answer (score 2):

Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion, too many factors go into determining how best a component should be sized and positioned.

Take the time to learn and understand how to make use of the available layout managers - see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).  Remember, you're not stuck to a single container/layout, you can compound these together to produce very complex UIs

For example, this is what your UI produces (when I fix the core issue)

[image: Original layout]

But if I make use of an appropriate layout managers I can produce...

## `GridBagLayout`

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;

            gbc.ipadx = 8;
            gbc.ipady = 8;

            JLabel title = new JLabel("Choose a Program");
            title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(title, gbc);

            JButton TempConverter = new JButton();
            TempConverter.setText("Temperature Converter");
            add(TempConverter, gbc);

            JButton CurrentTime = new JButton();
            CurrentTime.setText("Current Time");
            add(CurrentTime, gbc);

            JButton RussianRoulette = new JButton();
            RussianRoulette.setText("Russian Roulette");
            add(RussianRoulette, gbc);

            JButton DaysSinceLastTrinket = new JButton();
            DaysSinceLastTrinket.setText("Days Since Last Trinket");
            add(DaysSinceLastTrinket, gbc);

            JButton SimpleCalculator = new JButton();
            SimpleCalculator.setText("Simple Calculator");
            add(SimpleCalculator, gbc);
        }

    }
}
```

But, I appreciate that `GridBagLayout` is one of the most complex (and flexible) layout managers, but, we can try...

## "Compound" layout

We can isolate functionality to individual components, which can make use of their own layout managers, allowing us to focus on the individual components needs and then build up much more complex layouts...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JLabel title = new JLabel("Choose a Program");
            title.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
            title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            JPanel optionsPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(-1, 1));
            optionsPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));

            JButton TempConverter = new JButton();
            TempConverter.setMargin(new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8));
            TempConverter.setText("Temperature Converter");
            optionsPane.add(TempConverter);

            JButton CurrentTime = new JButton();
            CurrentTime.setText("Current Time");
            CurrentTime.setMargin(new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8));
            optionsPane.add(CurrentTime);

            JButton RussianRoulette = new JButton();
            RussianRoulette.setText("Russian Roulette");
            RussianRoulette.setMargin(new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8));
            optionsPane.add(RussianRoulette);

            JButton DaysSinceLastTrinket = new JButton();
            DaysSinceLastTrinket.setText("Days Since Last Trinket");
            DaysSinceLastTrinket.setMargin(new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8));
            optionsPane.add(DaysSinceLastTrinket);

            JButton SimpleCalculator = new JButton();
            SimpleCalculator.setText("Simple Calculator");
            SimpleCalculator.setMargin(new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8));
            optionsPane.add(SimpleCalculator);

            add(optionsPane);
        }

    }
}
```

*nb: If you want to change the order of the buttons, then change the order in which they are added*

Comment: both options seem fascinating! Thanks a lot for showing me both, GridBagLayout seems the simplest for larger-scale projects, allowing me to call on your instance of "gbc" whenever I need to add a separate button, one last question, with this method, how would you recommend calling on other functions when pressed, I have them locally in the code, just left them out to keep the post short

Comment: Generally, I'd use an anonymous `ActionListener` for each button or the `Action` API

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was wrong with my original code, im going to use the grid bag layout moving forward, but I'm still curious what you did to fix it

Comment: @AndrewDawson You have to set the frame's layout first